# mysql php random results sort by name

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I need to order by the name from the random results. My sql command:

```
SELECT * FROM oc_manufacturer ORDER BY RAND() ASC LIMIT 0,50
```

And it returns thhis array:

```
   [0] => Array
        (
            [manufacturer_id] => 16
            [name] => Azzaro
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [manufacturer_id] => 71
            [name] => Sony
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [manufacturer_id] => 104
            [name] => Casio
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [manufacturer_id] => 30
            [name] => Jeepers Peepers
        )
```

But i want to return first Azzaro, then Casio, then Jeepers Peepers, and Sony. I need to sort results by name from RAMDOM results. I tried sort arrays and some mysql commands but it is not worked.

Comment: You can use php's array sorting functions, or just wrap your query with another. E.g.: SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM oc_manufacturer ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 50)x ORDER BY name;

Comment: I tried array sorting ksort krsort asort arsort but I can't get good result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either

make a subquery (see Strawberry comment)

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM oc_manufacturer ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 50)x ORDER BY name;
```

---

sort the array in PHP

```
$array = ....; // make query
usort($array, function($item1, item2) {
    return strcmp($item1['name'], $item2['name']);
});
```